# How to dynamically use the source/target table for Merge & also dynamically select the columns for update statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, shell, scripting, plsqldeveloper

Facing problem in dynamically using the tables & columns for merge and update

Thanks in Advance

Below is the code which uses the static values for table names & column names

```
declare vsql varchar2(32767) ;
begin vsql := 
' merge into ' ||
' EDW tbl ' ||
' using ( ' ||
' select ' ||
' STG.pk, ' ||
' STG.data ' ||
' from ' ||
' STG ' ||
' where ' ||
' STG.pk = :1 ' ||
' ) qry ' ||
' on ( ' ||
' tbl.pk = qry.pk ' ||
' ) ' ||
' when matched then ' ||
' update ' ||
' set ' ||
' tbl.data = qry.data ' ||
' when not matched then ' ||
' insert ( ' ||
' tbl.pk, ' ||
' tbl.data ' ||
' ) values ( ' ||
' qry.pk, ' ||
' qry.data ' ||
' ) ' ;
execute immediate vsql using 1 ; 
end ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
' merge into ' ||
' EDW tbl ' ||
' using ( ' ||
' select ' ||
' STG.pk, ' ||
' STG.data ' ||
' from ' ||
' STG ' ||
' where ' ||
' STG.pk = :1 ' ||
' ) qry ' ||
' on ( ' ||
' tbl.pk = qry.pk ' ||
' ) ' ||
' when matched then ' ||
' update ' ||
' set ' ||
' tbl.data = qry.data ' ||
' when not matched then ' ||
' insert ( ' ||
' pk, ' ||
' data ' ||
' ) values ( ' ||
' qry.pk, ' ||
' qry.data ' ||
' ) ' ;
```

`tbl.pk` and `tbl.data` specify the *values* of the fields, not the field name.

Also, I don't see why you're building this statement as a string and using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE - it'd work just fine as:

```
DECLARE
  nVar  NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
  merge into EDW tbl
    using (select STG.pk,
                  STG.data 
             from STG 
             where STG.pk = nVar) qry 
      on (tbl.pk = qry.pk) 
    when matched then 
      update set tbl.data = qry.data 
    when not matched then 
   insert (pk, data)
     values (qry.pk, qry.data);
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry May be i didn't frame the question properly. Actually am trying to write the merge statement to a file & execute it later. Also the above code works for  single source table & target table. Is there is a way we can design a dynamic merge statement for pulling multiple source & target tables and update the corresponding columns dynamically using the sys owned table like ALL_COL_COMMENTS ??